# Store Tkinter Entry into new variable

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am writing a program that allows a user to input a certain temperature into a text box, and then display the corresponding graph based on the user input. I know the program works when I manually write in the start temperature, but I cannot seem to figure out how to get the user input value stored into the correct variable and then used. I will put the whole program below, however my problem is in the class called PageTwo. I want the value inputed to be stored as the variable name "Tc" which is used in the plot section of the page. I keep getting the error "AttributeError: 'PageTwo' object has no attribute 'ID1'". Any help would be appreciated.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import font as tkfont
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.title_font = tkfont.Font(family='Helvetica', weight="bold")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (PageTwo):
            page_name = F.__name__
            frame = F(parent=container, controller=self)
            self.frames[page_name] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame("StartPage")


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Temperature Distribution as a function of Distance")
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)


        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Finish & Plot", command=self.plot)
        button2.pack()

        var1 = StringVar()
        var1.set("Enter inner chamber temperature:")
        label1 = tk.Label(self, textvariable=var1, height=2)
        label1.pack()

        ID1 = StringVar()
        entry1 = tk.Entry(self, bd=4, textvariable=ID1)
        entry1.pack()

    def read_inputs(self):
        x = self.entry1.get()

    def plot(self):
        Tc = self.read_inputs()
        f = 49
        h1 = 50
        L1 = .05 
        L2 = .022  
        L3 = .1125
        k_sand = 0.27 
        k_water = 0.6  
        k_brick = 0.72 
        e_sand = 0.343  
        k_ws = e_sand * k_water + (1 - e_sand) * k_sand
        T4 = -((f * (1 / h1)) - Tc)
        T3 = -((f * (L1 / k_al)) - T4)
        T2 = -((f * (L2 / k_ws)) - T3)
        T1 = -((f * (L3 / k_brick)) - T2)

        print(T4, T3, T2, T1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't post an entire program. Instead, create a [mcve] specifically for the purposes of this question. Also, please make sure you get the formatting right on the code you post.

Comment: @BryanOakley I removed all of the unnecessary code, do you have any idea on how to get the user input to be stored into a variable that I am able to use in my plot statement?

Comment: Now your code won't run at all, and there still seems to be lots of unrelated code. If your question is about getting a value from an input, do we really need any of the matplotlib code?

Comment: @BryanOakley I need the value from the input to be stored as a variable name Tc which is then used in the matplotlib code to display a graph that requires a start value (the user input Tc).

Comment: Yes, I know, but the problem isn't with using the variable in matplotlib, the problem seems to be _getting_ the value, right? It doesn't matter if you're plotting it as a graph or simply printing it to stdout, the problem is the same.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes the problem is getting the value to be stored correctly.

Comment: Your problem seems to be simply that you haven't assigned `entry1` to `self`. Have you tried changing that one line to `self.entry1 = tk.Entry(...)`? This isn't a tkinter problem, this is simply how class attributes work in python.

Comment: @BryanOakley yes I have tried that and when I do this error returns:     in plot
    T4 = -((f * (1 / h1)) - Tc)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'NoneType'

Comment: Well, `read_inputs` isn't returning the value, which would explain that error.

Comment: Also, you still don't seem to have grasped the concept of [mcve]. The "c" stands for "complete", and the code you posted won't run for several reasons.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your code does not work. read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I'd recommend at least trying to run the code before posting it here...

your code does not work because you're trying to use `pack` inside an object which has slaves using `grid` when you call `self.pack` under the `PageOne` class. tkinter will never let you do this.

then you say the error you receive is `"AttributeError: 'PageTwo' object has no attribute 'ID1'"`. for this to be possible, you would need to declare the variable `ID1` with `self` *somewhere* inside the `PageTwo` class, which you do not.

in the init method of the PageTwo class, you declare the tkinter Entry widget as `entry1`.

later on you use `self.entry1` in your `read_inputs` function. so this is a simple fix, just declare `entry1` as`self.entry1`...

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        ID1 = StringVar()
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(self, bd=4, textvariable=ID1)
        self.entry1.pack()
        ...

    def read_inputs(self):
        x = self.entry1.get()
```

I cannot run your code to verify this, but I would wager that you cannot read the input due to that variable name being incorrect.

Comment: the code does run for me, the only problem I am having is getting the input from the entry1 and storing it as a new variable to be used in the graph portion.

Comment: The call to `self.pack` isn't really a problem here, since the code that creates the page later calls `grid` on that widget, so the effects of calling `pack` are nullified.

Comment: @BryanOakley My bad. You do not get the error `_tkinter.TclError: cannot use geometry manager pack inside .140481842351296 which already has slaves managed by grid` ?

Comment: @Amanda sorry, I cannot run your edited version as you call `app = SampleApp()` but the class `SampleApp` does not exist.

Comment: @spoiledgoods I added back in the first class so the code would be able to run, I also added some dummy variables to see if the user input would work in calculating the values for T4, T3, T2, and T1 which I then have printing at the end. Overall I just need to get the input from the user and store it as the variable Tc in the PageTwo class in order to be used later in calculations.

Comment: @Amanda as explained in my answer, when you call `read_inputs`, you're referencing a variable that doesn't exist. `entry1` and `self.entry1` aren't the same thing. you need to declare the variable with `self`.

Answer (score 0):

What you've described isn't a tkinter problem at all. You simply need to make the widget an attribute of the class, and then you need to convert and return the value from `read_inputs`:

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        ...
        self.entry1 = tk.Entry(...)
        ...

    def read_inputs(self):
        x = self.entry1.get()
        return float(x)
```